# Create a buffering video on seek, pause or play

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I want to create a buffer gif when user seeks, play or pause the video. I am able to succeed a bit but I can'f figure out how to do this on seek. This is my code.

HTML:

```
<div class="row text-center">
        <video width="320" height="240" controls id="video1" onplay="buffer(this.id)" poster="" class="">
            <source src="http://distribution.bbb3d.renderfarming.net/video/mp4/bbb_sunflower_1080p_30fps_normal.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="row text-center">
        <video width="320" height="240" controls id="video2" onplay="buffer(this.id)" poster="" class="">
            <source src="http://www.html5videoplayer.net/videos/toystory.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
video.loading {
        background: black url("img/loader_old.gif") center center no-repeat;
        z-index: 300000 !important;
    }
```

JQUERY:

```
function buffer(id){
    $('#'+id).on('loadstart', function (event) {
        $(this).addClass('loading');
    });
    $('#'+id).on('canplay', function (event) {
        $(this).removeClass('loading');
        $(this).attr('poster', '');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the value of `poster` attribute to `.gif` at `html`, remove value at `canplay` event, where you call `$(this).attr('poster', '');`

```
<div class="row text-center">
  <video width="320" height="240" controls id="video1" poster="img/loader_old.gif" class="">
    <source src="http://distribution.bbb3d.renderfarming.net/video/mp4/bbb_sunflower_1080p_30fps_normal.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="row text-center">
  <video width="320" height="240" controls id="video2" poster="img/loader_old.gif" class="">
    <source src="http://www.html5videoplayer.net/videos/toystory.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
</div>
```

```
$(function() {
  $("video").each(function() {
    $(this).on("canplay", function (event) {
        $(this).attr("poster", "");
    })
  })
});
```